# Testing an API with Jest in TypeScript

Tags: api, post, jestjs

Basically I'm trying to test a post API, using the following code:

```
import request from 'supertest';
import app from '../src/routes';


    describe("TDD create admin", () => {
        it("Should create a new administrator", async () => {  
            const data = {
                    nome: 'Organizador',
                    telefone: '69984595945',
                    endereco: 'rua das flores, jardim são joão',
                    email: 'email@organizador.com',
                    senha: 'senha123'
                };
    
            const res = await request(app)
                .post('/organizador')
                .send(data)
            expect(res.status).toEqual(201)
        })
    })
```

But I have this error, for having an undefined property, but I can use this route normally with insomnia.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nome' of undefined
 |     async create (request: Request, response: Response) {
      12 |         const {
    > 13 |             nome,
         |                 ^
      14 |             telefone,
      15 |             endereco,
      16 |             email,
      17 |             senha
      18 |         } = request.body
```

Comment: Did you add `bodyParser` as a middleware?

Comment: No, but I'm using the express.json, like this: app.use(express.json());

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this changing my server.ts file:

It looks like this now:

```
import express from 'express';
import routes from './routes';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(routes);


export default app;
```

I had to add the bodyParser and the export default, to consume in my test.